# Java-Stream - Grouping and Sorting based on aggregate count in Java 11

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I have a `Stream` of custom objects as a parameter to a method. And obviously I can consume the Stream only once.

My object has a `String` attribute called `category`.

```
public class MyType {
    private String category;
    
    // other properties, getters, etc.
}
```

I need a sorted list of categories `List<String>`.

First, I need to sort the data based on the number of occurrences of each category. If the number of occurrences is the same, then sort such categories lexicographically.

Basically, I need something like this

[java8 stream grouping and sorting on aggregate sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733052/java8-stream-grouping-and-sorting-on-aggregate-sum)

**but** I don't have the luxury of consuming the stream more than once. So I don't know how to address this problem.

Here's an example:

*Input:*

```
{
    object1 :{category:"category1"},
    object2 :{category:"categoryB"},
    object3 :{category:"categoryA"},
    object4 :{category:"category1"},
    object5 :{category:"categoryB"},
    object6 :{category:"category1"},
    object7 :{category:"categoryA"}
}
```

*Output:*

```
List = {category1, categoryA, categoryB}
```

Comment: Hello @SarthakShetty Is it possible to first make a List from your Stream and then you process it multiple times again using the Stream-API? First Stream.toList() and then List.stream().

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but it seems a little counter-intuitive since the objective for me to use streams was for efficiency. Or am I wrong about that? Relatively new to the stream API.

Comment: Could you share some input and expected output? I'll make the question more clear.

Comment: Anyway, you cannot sort and count at the same time, as the order can change until the very last item you encounter. So you first need to determine all occurrences, and then you can start soring.

Comment: @SarthakShetty You are right, it would be more efficient to process the stream in one go. Given your requirement, that will force you to load the whole stream into a cache. But sorting is anyway doing this in the back ;-). The benefit to solve the problem by streaming again the list is just to have a more concise way to express your code (declarative), but could be done in a imperative way as well.

Comment: updated to include an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a Map of frequencies for each category of type `Map<String,Long>` (*count by category*).

Then create a stream over its entries and sort them (*by Value, i.e. by count, and Key, i.e. lexicographically*), extract the category from each entry and store the result into a list.

Assuming that you have the following domain type:

```
public class MyType {
    private String category;
    
    // getters
}
```

Method generating a sorted list of categories might be implemented like this:

```
public static List<String> getSortedCategories(Stream<MyType> stream) {
    
    return stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyType::getCategory,
            Collectors.counting()
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(
            Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue()
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        )
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .toList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! I guess I didn't realise I could stream after grouping :)

Comment: @MJG The sorting is done by both frequency and name of category as mentioned in the description and more importantly reflected in the code, so I'm not quite sure what do you mean.